# unexplained IllegalArgument during invocation of `implode`

Tags: dsl, rascal

I tried to make a DSL in Rascal for a subset of the cmake language, but there is an IllegalArgument exception during the call to `implode` which is hard to debug.

CMake.rsc:

```
module CMake

import util::IDE;
import ParseTree;
import String;
import IO;
import Node;

import Implode;
import AST;
import Syntax;
import Parse;

private str STM_LANG = "CMakeLists";
private str STM_EXT = "cmake"; // change to txt

public void main() {
  registerLanguage(STM_LANG, STM_EXT, Tree(str src, loc location) {
     print("parse\n");
     return parse(src, location);
  });

    contribs = {
        builder(set[Message] (start[Build] pt) {
            ctl = implode(pt);
                out = (pt@\loc)[extension="txt"];
                class = split(".", out.file)[0];
                print("build\n");
//              writeFile(out, compile(class, ctl));
            return {};
        })
    };

    registerContributions(STM_LANG, contribs);    
}
```

Syntax.rsc:

```
module Syntax

extend lang::std::Layout;

start syntax Build = build: Section+ sections;

layout Layout = Comment*;
lexical Comment = @category="Comment" "#" ![\n]* [\n]; 

syntax Section = section: Target target Options+ options;
syntax Target = target: "set" "(" Id targetMacro Id targetName ")";
syntax Options = options: IdeFolder Dirs Sources+; 
syntax IdeFolder = ideFolder: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" "_IDE_FOLDER" "\"" Id ideFolderPath "\"" ")";
syntax Dirs = dirs: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" "_DIRS" DirsPath+ dirPaths ")";
syntax DirsPath = dirPaths: "$" "{" Id pathMacro "}" Id? path;
syntax Sources = sources: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" ("_SOURCES" | "_WINDOWS_SOURCES" ) Id+ sourceFiles ")";

lexical Id = ([a-zA-Z/.][a-zA-Z0-9_/.]* !>> [a-zA-Z0-9_/.]) \ Reserved ;
keyword Reserved = "set" | "$" | "{" | "}" | "_IDE_FOLDER" | "_DIRS" | "_SOURCES" | "_WINDOWS_SOURCES";
```

AST.rsc:

```
module AST

data Build = build(list[Section] sections);
data Section = section(Target target, list[IdeFolder] ideFolders);
data Target = target(str targetMacro, str targetName);
data Options = options(IdeFolder ideFolder); 
data IdeFolder = ideFolder(str targetMacro, str ideFolderPath);
data Dirs = dirs(str targetMacro, list[DirsPath] dirPaths);
data DirsPath = dirPaths(str pathMacro, str path);
data Sources = sources(str targetMacro, list[str] sourceFiles);

anno loc Build@location;
anno loc Section@location;
anno loc Options@location;
anno loc Target@location;
anno loc IdeFolder@location;
anno loc Dirs@location;
anno loc DirsPath@location;
anno loc Sources@location;
```

Parse.rsc:

```
module Parse

import Syntax;
import ParseTree;

public start[Build] parse(str src, loc origin) = parse(#start[Build], src, origin);
public start[Build] parse(loc origin) = parse(#start[Build], origin);
```

Implode.rsc:

```
module Implode

import Parse;
import AST;

import ParseTree;
import Node;

public Build implode(Tree pt) = implode(#Build, pt);
public Build load(loc l) = implode(#Build, parse(l));
```

CMakeLists.cmake:

```
# test

set(TARGET_NAME bb)

set(${TARGET_NAME}_IDE_FOLDER "test")

set(${TARGET_NAME}_DIRS
  ${BLA_PATH}/src
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}/dir1/pub
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}/dir2/pub
) 

set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES
  ../inc/file3.h
  ../inc/file4.h
)
```

The error message is:

```
|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(17152,5150,<507,0>,<652,60>): IllegalArgument(appl(prod(label("build",sort("Build")),[label("sections",\iter-seps(sort("Section"),[layouts("Standard")]))],{}),[appl(regular(\iter-seps(sort("Section"),[layouts("Standard")])),[appl(prod(label("section",sort("Section")),[label("target",sort("Target")),layouts("Standard"),label("options",\iter-seps(sort("Options"),[layouts("Standard")]))],{}),[appl(prod(label("target",sort("Target")),[lit("set"),layouts("Standard"),lit("("),layouts("Standard"),label("targetMacro",lex("Id")),layouts("Standard"),label("targetName",lex("Id")),layouts("Standard"),lit(")")],{}),[appl(prod(lit("set"),[\char-class([range(115,115)]),\char-class([range(101,101)]),\char-class([range(116,116)])],{}),[char(115),char(101),char(116)]),appl(prod(layouts("Standard"),[conditional(\iter-star(lex("WhitespaceOrComment")),{\not-follow(\char-class([range(9,13),range(32,32),range(133,133),range(160,160),range(5760,5760),range(6158,6158),range(8192,8202),range(8232,8233),range(8239,8239),range(8287,8287),range(12288,12288)])),\not-follow(lit("//"))})],{}),[appl(regular(\iter-star(lex("WhitespaceOrComment"))),[])[@loc=|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|(15,0,<4,3>,<4,3>)]])[@loc=|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|(15,0,<4,3>,<4,3>)],appl(prod(lit("("),[\char-class([range(40,40)])],{}),[char(40)]),appl(prod(layouts("Standard"),[conditional(\iter-star(lex("WhitespaceOrComment")),{\not-follow(\char-class([range(9,13),range(32,32),range(133,133),range(160,160),range(5760,5760),range(6158,6158),range(8192,8202),range(8232,8233),range(8239,8239),range(8287,8287),range(12288,12288)])),\not-follow(lit("//"))})],{}),[appl(regular(\iter-star(lex("WhitespaceOrComment"))),[])[@loc=|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|(16,0,<4,4>,<4,4>)]])[@loc=|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|(16,0,<4,4>,<4,4>)],appl(prod(lex("Id"),[conditional(seq([\char-class([range(46,47),range(65,90),range(97,122)]),conditional(\iter-star(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)])),{\not-follow(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)]))})]),{delete(keywords("Reserved"))})],{}),[appl(regular(seq([\char-class([range(46,47),range(65,90),range(97,122)]),conditional(\iter-star(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)])),{\not-follow(\char-class([range(46,57),range(65,90),range(95,95),range(97,122)]))})])),[char(84),appl(regular(
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(17152,5150,<507,0>,<652,60>))
        at implode(|project://Instrumentation/src/Implode.rsc|(131,2,<9,48>,<9,50>))
        at Anonymous Function(|project://Instrumentation/src/CMake.rsc|(481,12,<25,9>,<25,21>))
        at $root$(|main://$root$|)
    ...truncated here...
```

Comment: fixed code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Cool project!

After @Matty split the example code into different modules we eliminated the possibility of confusion between the different syntax and data types.

So here's a debugging session:

```
rascal>x = parse(#start[Build], |project://rascal-test-project/src/CMakeLists.cmake|);
start[Build]: (start[Build]) `# test

set(TARGET_NAME bb)

set(${TARGET_NAME}_IDE_FOLDER "test")

set(${TARGET_NAME}_DIRS
  ${BLA_PATH}/src
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}/dir1/pub
  ${BLA_GEN_PATH}/dir2/pub
) 

set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES
  ../inc/file3.h
  ../inc/file4.h
)

rascal>try { 
>>>>>>>  implode(#AST::Build, t); 
>>>>>>>} 
>>>>>>>catch IllegalArgument(x, m): 
>>>>>>>  println(m);
Cannot find a constructor for Build
ok
```

The IllegalArgument exception has both  the argument and a reason. Since the argument was so long, it got truncated by the terminal and we could not read the message :-( The message is that `Build` can not find an abstract constructor to match the tree.

Let's look into the abstract grammar to see if we are missing the constructor, or that it is there anyway:

```
rascal>iprintln(#AST::Build)
type(
  adt(
    "Build",
    []),
  (
    adt(
      "IdeFolder",
      []): ..., // elided
    adt(
      "Target",
      []): ..., // elided
    adt(
      "Build",  // bingo!
      []):choice(
      adt(
        "Build",
        []),
      {cons(   // this is the constructor it should have found 
               // data Build = build(list[Section] sections);
          label(
            "build",
            adt(
              "Build",
              [])),
          [label(
              "sections",
              list(adt(
                  "Section",
                  [])))],
          [],
          {})}),
    })
  ))
ok
```

It seems we have a constructor to work with. So what is going on? I stepped through the code of `implode` in Java to find out that the real reason was hidden by a bug in the backtracking part of implode. That's now fixed (see next continuous release on the update site).

The current, better, error message is:

```
rascal>try { implode(#AST::Build, x); } catch IllegalArgument (t, m) : println("<m> : <t>");
Cannot find a constructor for IdeFolder with name options and arity 3 for syntax type 'Options' : set(${TARGET_NAME}_IDE_FOLDER "test")
```

So this means that the implode algorithm has reached a syntax rule named `options` of type `Options` with 3 children, while at the same time expecting an IdeFolder in the abstract data-type.

This means an intermediate level is missing in the data type definitions:

```
data Section = section(Target target, list[IdeFolder] ideFolders);
```

can be changed to:

```
data Section = section(Target target, list[Options] ideFolders);
```

Next try:

```
try { implode(#AST::Build, x); } catch IllegalArgument (t, m) : println("<m> : <t>");

Cannot find a constructor for Options with name options and arity 3 for syntax type 'Options' : set(${TARGET_NAME}_IDE_FOLDER "test")
```

Now the names align, but the arity does not. Let's fix that:

```
syntax Options = options: IdeFolder Dirs Sources+;
data Options = options(IdeFolder ideFolder); // has to change to:
data Options = options(IdeFolder ideFolder, Dirs dirs, list[Sources] sources);
```

And we get the next error:

```
rascal>try { implode(#AST::Build, x); } catch IllegalArgument (t, m) : println("<m> : <t>");
Cannot find a constructor for Sources with name sources and arity 3 for syntax type 'Sources' : set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES
  ../inc/file3.h
  ../inc/file4.h
)
```

You get the idea now :-) You have some more things to fix in your AST.rsc. Thanks for asking the question. We just made implode a little better together.

Comment: I placed syntax, parse, implode and AST in separate modules, but I still get the following error: "|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(17152,5150,<507,0>,<652,60>): IllegalArgument(appl(prod(label("build",sort("Build")),...
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(17152,5150,<507,0>,<652,60>))
        at implode(|project://Instrumentation/src/Implode.rsc|(131,2,<9,48>,<9,50>))
        at Anonymous Function(|project://Instrumentation/src/CMake.rsc|(481,12,<25,9>,<25,21>))
        at $root$(|main://$root$|)"

Comment: Ok. That's mysterious. We have to dig a little. At least make sure to start a fresh terminal, so we have a clean slate. Is the stack trace this short or is there more to it?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed debug session. I try to replicate it in my environment. But I already fail at the first step: `rascal>try {x = parse(#start[Build], |project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|);} catch CallFailed(m) : printl("<n>");
|prompt:///|(30,48,<1,30>,<1,78>): CallFailed(
  |prompt:///|(30,48,<1,30>,<1,78>),
  [
    type(
      start(sort("Build")),
      (
     ... // too long
      )),
    |project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|
  ])
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(9,71,<1,9>,<1,80>))
ok`

Comment: Or with try catch: `rascal>try {x = parse(#start[Build], |project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|);} catch CallFailed(m, e) : println("<m>, <e>");
|prompt:///|(30,48,<1,30>,<1,78>), [type(start(sort("Build")),(layouts("$default$"):choice(layouts("$default$"),{prod(layouts("$default$"),[],{})}),empty():choice(empty(),{prod(empty(),[],{})}))),|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|]
ok`

Comment: First you have to update to the latest unstable release from the update site. You can catch the IllegalArgument exception which has 2 parameters, and there is a typo in your call to println. I'm on holiday now, so it may take a while for me to reply.

Comment: I created a fresh install of Eclipse and use the newest unstable version of Rascal. rascal>x = parse(|project://Instrumentation/src/test.cmake|); now passes and prints the language instance on the console. With iprintln(x); I can print the tree. Cannot find a constructor for Sources with name sources and arity 3 for syntax type 'Sources' : set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES
  ../inc/file3.h
  ../inc/file4.h
). So I guess I need an Id for ("_SOURCES" | "_WINDOWS_SOURCES" | "_OBJ_TN_SOURCES" ) so I changed that line.

Comment: I also changed Id to allow it to start with "_" see lexical Id = ([a-zA-Z/._][a-zA-Z0-9_/.]* !>> [a-zA-Z0-9_/.]) \ Reserved ; But it does not parse for some reason: rascal>try {x = parse(|project://Instrumentation/src/test.cmake|); } catch ParseError(l): println(l);
|project://Instrumentation/src/test.cmake|(227,1,<15,26>,<15,27>)
ok which is the following line "set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES"

Comment: Without try/catch: rascal>x = parse(|project://Instrumentation/src/test.cmake|);
|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>): ParseError(|project://Instrumentation/src/test.cmake|(227,1,<15,26>,<15,27>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(4,50,<1,4>,<1,54>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(4,50,<1,4>,<1,54>))

Comment: I have syntax Sources = sources: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" ("_SOURCES" | "_WINDOWS_SOURCES" ) Id+ sourceFiles ")"; and data Sources = sources(str targetMacro, list[str] sourceFiles); I do not understand why it expects a constructor with arity 3

Comment: The | notation introduces another level in the tree, so that's one child. Then there is the Id field and the Id+ field, so that's 3. I'm not sure implode supports the | notation... Better try an extra rule for that?

Comment: Implode does not seem to support the | notation. But I can work around it.

Comment: with visit (ast) case f:\configureTestExecutable(_,_) I match a test. I want to print the location of the test in the source file. With Clair I can do this with f.src. But with my own DSL and AST I am unable to do this. src and location do not exist.

Comment: @Matty that's interesting. How did you obtain the AST?

Comment: If you used the `implode` function, it could be you're only missing this declaration: `data MyTestType(loc etc=|unknown://|);`

Comment: I do use implode. I have "anno loc ConfigureTestExecutable@location;" which I thought would do it. I added data ConfigureTestExecutable(loc etc=|unknown://|); but this does not solve the problem

Comment: Etc should be src

Comment: And it depends on the version if you need to use @src for annotations or .src for a keyword field. That has changed

Comment: I use unstable version 0.12.0.201906031040

Comment: I do not know why, but println("<f@location.offset>"); seems to work :-)

Comment: Can I make the notation consistent for Clair and my own DSL?

Comment: That is possible I think by upgrading to the latest unstable release, perhaps even to the latest stable; but it requires some patience of you and you can't go back!